# Android insert data into a live mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am trying to insert data from edit texts to a live database but the app crashes when i press the button which should send data.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button add_btn,view_btn;
    TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    view_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_btn);
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {   
        add_btn.setEnabled(false);
        view_btn.setEnabled(false);
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
public void add_user(View view){

    startActivity(new Intent(this,Add_user.class));

}
public void view_user(View view){


}

        }


       public class Add_user extends Activity {
    EditText name,username,pass;
    Button add_user;
   String name1,username1,pass1,method;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    add_user=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
public void add(View view){
    name1=name.getText().toString();
    username1=username.getText().toString();
    pass1=pass.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(name1,username1,pass1);
    finish();
}
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        url="http://douxtoile.com/add_user.php";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name=params[1];
        String username=params[2];
        String pass=params[3];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name+""+username+""+pass,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {

                URL url1=new URL(url);
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os=httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                String data=URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();
            InputStream is=httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();
            httpsURLConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 0).show();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "Success";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
 }
```

Here is my Error log.

```
Stacktrace: 
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090): FATAL EXCEPTION:        AsyncTask #2
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090): Process:     com.example.demo_online_db, PID: 24090
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at com.example.demo_online_db.Add_user$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Add_user.java:54)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at com.example.demo_online_db.Add_user$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(Add_user.java:1)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
          03-07 16:05:34.324: E/AndroidRuntime(24090):  ... 4 more
          03-07 16:05:35.985: E/OpenGLRenderer(24090): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
```

I have not included any external jars actually i am new to this so dont know exactly if i am doing this the right way or wrong. 
Php script is fine i have tested it statically.

Comment: Why are you calling `finish()` after starting a background task?

Comment: `String name=params[0];
        String username=params[1];
        String pass=params[2];`

Comment: @PavneetSingh Oh I missed that.

Comment: to get back to the previous activity.

Comment: app crashes with a dialog saying unfortunately app_name has stopped

Comment: It may cause memory leaks this way.

Comment: Finish the activity only after the Background task is finished. Or create an Service to push changes to your live sql database.

Comment: what should i do then for memory leak prevention as well as stopping the app from crashing?

Comment: i didnt get it.

Comment: call `backgroundTask.execute();`. Inside `onPostExecute() {... finish()}`

Answer (score 1):

Get your string values in this way...

```
        String name=params[0];
        String username=params[1];
        String pass=params[2];
```

Comment: You could wrap the Toast in runOnUIThread() but this isn't the best solution.
You should set a boolean flag in the catch block when an error occurs, then display an appropriate Toast in onProgressUpdate(), onPostExecute(), or any of the other methods with UI access whenever the flag is true

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 changes here

1)

```
public void add(View view){
    name1=name.getText().toString();
    username1=username.getText().toString();
    pass1=pass.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(name1,username1,pass1);
    //finish();
}
```

2)

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String name=params[0];
    String username=params[1];
    String pass=params[2];
```

3)

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: still the app is crashing. even if I comment all code in doInBackground and print a toast that is not working the app crashes.

Comment: attach new log cat here after commenting out `backgroundTask.execute(name1,username1,pass1);`

Comment: 03-07 16:46:47.156: D/ViewRootImpl(15597): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN